# How to slide to another html page in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, slide

I'm trying to make a web page to time a race and I had the idea to make the html page with the timer slide from the right with hitting a button

here's the html of the main menu:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<body style="background:#f2f2f2;">

<div id="options" style="background:#0c0c0c; float:right;">
    <div class="menu" onclick="openChronometre()" ></div>
</div>

</body>
```

[here's a js fiddle of the main menu (without images)](http://jsfiddle.net/1uggfw32/4/)

[here's a js fiddle of the timer (the layout isn't that great, still WIP)](http://jsfiddle.net/w55tzy7L/)

when hitting the black bar in the main menu, the entire page html page for the timer should come from the right, is there any way to do that?

Comment: Is the cronometer already in the page? or is it an external page that you are loading somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I didn't do the animation part. But as a basic idea...

You're probably better off keeping the timer as a div on the main menu page. 
If it has to be another page then use an iframe or ajax to load the contents to the div I guess.

Either way it should be contained in the element you're clicking on. Then you can use some JavaScript to modify the CSS and show it/slide it on the page. The jQuery library has a lot of animation/slide functions for example.

I basically combined your 2 fiddles into one and added:
`#options {position: absolute; left: 90%; }`
and
`onclick="opts = document.getElementById('options'); if (opts.style.left == '0px') { opts.style.left = '90%'; } else { opts.style.left = '0px';}"`

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Century Gothic';
  font-size: 34px;
}
#options {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-right: -8px;
  height: 450px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  left: 90%;
}
#Chrono1,
#Chrono2 {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 #0c0c0c;
  padding: 6px 20px;
}
#Panel1,
#Panel2 {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 #0c0c0c;
  width: 400px;
  height: 450px;
}
#Panel1:hover,
#Panel2:hover {
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -webkit-animation: PanelSlide 2s;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: PanelSlide 2s;
  /* IE */
}
```

```html
<body style="background:#f2f2f2;">

  <div id="options" style="background-color: #262626; font-family: Century Gothic; color: #8c8c8c;" onclick="opts = document.getElementById('options');
    if (opts.style.left == '0px') {
        opts.style.left = '90%';
    } else {
        opts.style.left = '0px';
    }
">
    <div id="Title" style="font-size: 55px; text-align: center; margin-top: 3%">Timer</div>

    <div id="Temps" style="text-align: center; font-size: 30px; margin: 7%;">
      <div id="Chrono1" style="display: inline-block; margin-right: 540px; position:relative;">
        00:00:00
      </div>

      <div id="Chrono2" style="display: inline-block; position:relative;">
        00:00:00
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Panels" style="text-align: center; font-size: 30px; margin-top: -5%;">
      <div id="Panel1" style="display: inline-block; position:relative; margin-right: 300px; opacity: 0;">

      </div>

      <div id="Panel2" style="display: inline-block; position:relative; opacity: 0;">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: That doesn't look exactly like what I had in mind but this looks really good, I might keep it that way instead! thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Just have (or load) the chronometre page in a div that is outside of the visibility, then use the animations to slide it in:

```
#next_page {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:100%;
    z-index:222;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
```

And then with JS (I used jQuery for convenience):

```
function openChronometre(){
    $("#next_page").stop(0,0).animate(
        { left: 0 },
        1000
    );
}
```

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/1uggfw32/5/ (I made the options as a green box so you can click on them).

Comment: the problem with having it all in one page is that I'm afraid it's going to be unreadable, but it looks like that's the only way to do it :/

Comment: That's why I mentioned the "(or load)" in my response: you can have it on a separate page and after you click on the option button, load the chronometer page using AJAX and do the animation (once it is loaded)

Comment: AJAX? never heard of it, I might look that up